# Problema al enviar un json con ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo es código javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "includes/acciones/examen/insert_respuestas.php",
        data: "id_usuario=" + id_usuario + "&id_examen=" + id_examen + "&respuestas=" + JSON.stringify(preguntas_contestadas),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data)
        { 
            if(data == 1)
            {
                revisarExamen();
            }
            else
            {
                Swal.fire('Error', 'Hubo un problema al registrar las respuetas', 'error');
                $("#btn-examen").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
});
```

En el arreglo `preguntas_contestadas` guardo objetos como muestro en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
var objRespuesta = {
                      "id_pregunta" : $("#respuestaVal").parent(0).children("#id_preguntaVal").val(),
                      "respuesta" : encodeURIComponent($("#respuestaVal").val()),
                      "correcto" : "",
                      "archivo" : ""
                   }

preguntas_contestadas.push(objRespuesta);
```

**insert_respuestas.php**

```
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Examen.php");

extract($_POST);
# id_usuario
# id_examen
# respuestas

$examen = new Examen($id_examen);

$respuestas = json_decode(stripslashes($respuestas));

$insert = 0;
$aciertos = 0;

foreach($respuestas as $respuesta)
{
    $id_respuesta = $examen->insertRespuesta($id_usuario, $respuesta->id_pregunta, addslashes(nl2br($respuesta->respuesta)), $respuesta->correcto, $respuesta->archivo);
    
    if($examen->tipo == 1 || $examen->tipo == 2)
    {
        if($respuesta->respuesta == $respuesta->correcto)
        {
            $valor_pregunta = Examen::getPreguntaValor($respuesta->id_pregunta);
            Examen::updatePuntos($id_respuesta, $valor_pregunta);
            $aciertos++;
        }
        else
        {
            Examen::updatePuntos($id_respuesta, 0);
        }
    }
    
    if($id_respuesta >= 1)
        $insert = 1;
    else
    {
        $insert = 0;
        break;
    }
}

if($insert == 1)
    echo 1;
else
    echo 0;
?>
```

Lo que necesito hacer es enviar con ajax ese arreglo como json a php, el problema viene cuando en la propiedad `respuesta` del `objRespuesta` se guarda un **salto de linea**, ya que en este caso no se envía ningún json pero si no se guarda un **salto de linea** envía el json correctamente.

Como puedo solucionar esto??

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente; modificando tu `data` del `ajax`:

```
data: JSON.stringify(
 {
   id_usuario: id_usuario,
   id_examen : id_examen,
   respuestas : preguntas_contestadas
 }
)
```